# How can be possible $\cap R_M=R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm doing this question in Hungerford's book:

[image]

I didn't understand how can be possible this intersection be equal to $R$, because $R_M$ is $S^{-1}R$ with $S=R-M$, maybe the author means they are isomorphic? I need a hint to begin to solve this question.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you're copying an exercise verbatim, it is good to say where it is from, i.e. author and book.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff yes, thank you for the remark

Comment: The localization maps $R\to R_M$ and $R_M \to F$ ($F$ the quotient field) are all injective (since $R$ is an integral domain), so you want to *identify* $R$ and $R_M$ with their isomorphic copy inside $F$.

Comment: Incidentally, this means that the difficult inclusion is $\bigcap R_M \subset R$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that Hungerford says to consider $R_M$ as a subring of the quotient field of $R$.  So it consists of the elements $s^{-1}r$ for all $r\in R$ and all $s\in S=R-M$.  With this in mind, the intersection, over all maximal ideals $M$, of the rings $R_M$ is literally equal to $R$ (as Hungerford says), not just isomorphic.

It is clear (by using $s=1$), that $R$ is included in every $R_M$ and therefore in the intersection.  The meat of the question is that, if an element of the quotient field can be expressed as $s^{-1}r$ in (possibly) many different ways, with all the $r$'s in $R$ and all the $s$'s outside various maximal ideals, then that element is in $R$, i.e., you don't actually need any $s^{-1}$ factors to express it.  HINT: The point is that your element has, for each maximal ideal $M$, an expression of the form $s^{-1}r$ with $s$ outside $M$.  The $s$'s that occur here, for all the various $M$'s, must generate the improper (i.e., unit) ideal of $R$, since no maximal ideal contains them all.  So write $1$ as a finite linear combination of some of these $s$'s and then use that to manipulate the corresponding expressions $s^{-1}r$.

Comment: I have the following questions: 1)In the second paragraph $s^{-1}$ is the inverse of $s$?2)Why $R_M$ a subring of the quotient field of $R$ implies that it consists of the elements $s^{-1}r$ for all $r\in R$ and all $s\in S=R-M$? thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: For your first question, yes, $s^{-1}$ is the inverse of $s$.  For the second, many people *define* $R_M$ to consist of these fractions $s^{-1}r$, and in fact it seems you said this in the question: "$R_M$ is $S^{-1}R$ with $S=R-M$." If you want to use some other definition, you should say which definition you want (perhaps the universal property?).

Comment: I didn't understand, for me $r/s$ is different than $s^{-1}r$. The former is an equivalence class in $S^{-1}R$ and the latter is the multiplication of the inverse of $s$ with r.

Comment: The distinction you mention between $r/s$ and $s^{-1}r$ is reasonable in the abstract, but obliterating this distinction is precisely how one considers $R_M$ as a subring of the quotient field of $R$; one identifies the element $r/s$ of the abstract localization with the element $s^{-1}r$ of the quotient field.